# Best way to allow users to add text in another language

Tags: xamarin.forms, globalization, cultureinfo, iso-639

I have a Xamarin Forms app where users enter the pieces of information they want to gather on a form.  The user provides a caption for each piece of information.  I want to allow the user to enter a caption for each piece of information in multiple languages.  I was wondering if there was a best practice for doing this?

My thought was to load all the ISO-639-1 codes into a list in the app and let the user select from the list of ISO-639-1 languages.  Then they could enter the caption for each piece of information in that language.  Any other thoughts?

FYI - I want to use the ISO 639-1 codes as the key for the language in the app as that is what the CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName line of code returns in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: If I understand right, when people want to text in a language, he has to have the corresponding keyboard,right? How do you make sure whether user has the corresponding keyboard of language select from the list of ISO-639-1?

Comment: That is a good point.  I would probably change the keyboard programmatically when the user chooses a language from the dropdown list.

Comment: Yeah, it would be an approach if you can change the keyboard programmatically when the user chooses a language from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up loading a list of languages based on the ISO_639_1_Code into an object in my application.  This is all hard coded fyi.  Then I have a combobox where the user selects the language they would like to add translated captions for.  When they enter the new languages, I save them in the app with the language code set as the ISO_639_1_Code.  This is working fine for me.